# Non-EEA spouse wanting to travel to UK with EEA citizen

Tags: visas, uk, south-african-citizens

I'm a South African married to a Portuguese for 13 years. We live in Zimbabwe permanently, and we want to travel together as a family with my EEA kids to visit family.

Please could you advise me on what documents I require when travelling with my spouse to the UK? Do I need an invitation letter from my brother-in-law who we will be staying with?

Comment: See https://www.gov.uk/family-permit

Answer (score 1):

you should apply for a EEA Family Permit from where you live!

Here in Brazil it is done through a company called VFS GLOBAL...

I've applied for it and it was refused due to the absence of the original marriage certificate, call me stupid I give you that, I sent only the legal translated copy, I figured that would cover since they don't know portuguese...

Anyway, since there is no more time to apply again and get it all back before Christmas (it all took 15 running days here in Sao Paulo) I'm going without the EEA Permit visa stamped and I wish to hand all docs at immigration, including the refusal letter sent to me...

I'm doing it confidently because my wife is already there for 3 months and she has everything (proven through docs) to be considered a qualified person!

My flight is on the 12/12, wish me luck!

Cheers,